# How to act on s3 bucket ACLs using bucket tags in Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am writing a Lambda script to automatically revert an s3 bucket's public ACL back to private unless the bucket is tagged with `"public-allowed" = "True"`. My script is successful in reverting the ACL, however I am having problems getting it to recognize the specified tag set.

I have found suggestions elsewhere saying to modify `tag.id` to `tag['id']` (so, `tag['name']`), however when I do that, instead of it saying `'dict' object has no attribute 'name'`, it simply says `name` in the logs as if I had `print(name)` in there. Doing this also has no effect on the outcome.

```
#Public Tag
def public_bucket(bucketname):

    try:
        bucket_tagging = s3.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucketname)
        tag_set = bucket_tagging['TagSet']
        for tag in tag_set:
            if (tag.name == "public-allowed"):
                if (tag.value == "True"):
                    return True
                    break
    except Exception, e:
        print(e.message)
```

I was expecting this to check through the tags that exist on the bucket and break the loop when it finds the specific key/value of `"public-allowed" = "True"`, which would allow the bucket ACL to stay public, and if there are no tags then print the error message. Instead, it still reverts the ACL to private regardless, although there are no actual errors being thrown.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get some more information from a co-worker, and this turns out that I needed to define the tags with `['Key']` and `['Value']`:

```
def public_bucket(bucketname):

    try:
        bucket_tagging = s3.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucketname)
        tag_set = bucket_tagging['TagSet']
        for tag in tag_set:
            if (tag['Key'] == "public-allowed"):
                if (tag['Value'] == "True"):
                    return True
                    break
    except Exception, e:
        print(e.message)
```

Sorry if me asking this question (and then answering myself) is bad stack overflow etiquette. Hopefully it's useful to others if nothing else.

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly fine. By the way, [Amazon S3 Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html) can do a similar job. With one button you can tell the bucket to ignore ACLs that grant public access.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, John! I know about the account level block, it's just not an applicable solution at this time.

Comment: FYI, it can also control public access at the bucket level, not just the whole account.

Comment: The solution I am developing has more to do with security automation than anything. Is there possibly an easier way to accomplish that aspect that I'm not seeing/aware of?